# Running a script inside a daemonized java process and killing the process

Tags: java, shell, systemd, runtime.exec

I have a Java program that starts a script which does some job job1 and kills the java program and does some other job job2. It works great except one situation.
When the java program is systemd daemon, the kill command kills also the daemon. So only job1 is done, job2 is never done.

How can I implement above scenario?

I have played with different "nohup ..." scenarios, but never achieved.

Here are the files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jvmName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    String pid = jvmName.split("@")[0];
    System.out.println(pid);
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nohup ./start.sh " + pid + " & > /dev/null 2>&1 &", new String[] {},
                new File("/home/someuser/eclipse-workspace/nohup/"));


        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exitCode);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'start ' $(date) >>deneme.txt
echo $1 >>deneme.txt
echo $$ >>deneme.txt
sleep 10
kill -9 $1
sleep 10
echo 'end ' $(date) >>deneme.txt
```

This is the systemd definition

```
[Unit]
Description=Nohup Deneme
After=syslog.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser/eclipse-workspace/nohup
SyslogIdentifier=montaigne
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "java -jar /home/someuser/eclipse-workspace/nohup/deneme.jar"
User=someuser
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit:

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491689/5236126 .

When I trap SIGTERM, I can now handle it.

```
#!/bin/bash

job1()
{
  echo 'deneme started'
  echo 'start ' $(date) >>deneme.txt
  echo 'version ' $2 >>deneme.txt
  echo 'process to be killed: ' $1 >>deneme.txt
  echo 'pid: ' $$ >>deneme.txt
  echo 'parent: ' $PPID >>deneme.txt    
}

job2()
{
  echo "Caught Signal " $1 " ... cleaning up." >>deneme.txt
  sleep 4
  echo 'parent after kill: ' $PPID >>deneme.txt
  echo 'end ' $(date) >>deneme.txt
  echo 'deneme stopped'
  exit 1
}


trap job2 15
job1
sleep 5
kill -9 $1 >>deneme.txt
sleep 1
job2 'no-signal'
```

Comment: Why not get rid of the Java wrapper code and just have `systemd`  `start.sh` directly?  There would be no need to use `nohup`-- systemd is already running the service in the background for you.

Comment: @MarkStosberg do you mean setting start.sh as daemon service?

Comment: Yes. Or depending what `start.sh` does, perhaps it is also a wrapper that be replaced by `systemd` service directives as well.